# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) MINIX3

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, minix

I am trying to run a C/C++ application on MINIX3 which is supposed to send a messages between two processes using msgsnd() and msgget() using msg.h.

This is the error I am getting:

```
send.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `msgget'
send.cpp:(.text+0x1c1): undefined reference to `msgsnd'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using clang++ to compile the code:

```
clang++ send.cpp -o send.out
```

This is the send.cpp code:

```
#include <lib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MSGSZ     128
/*
* Declare the message structure.
*/

typedef struct msgbufer {
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MSGSZ];
} message_buf;

int main()
{
    int msqid;
    int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    key_t key;
    message_buf sbuf;
    size_t buf_length;

    /*
    * Get the message queue id for the
    * "name" 1234, which was created by
    * the server.
    */
    key = 1234;

    (void)fprintf(stderr, "\nmsgget: Calling msgget(%i,\
                          %#o)\n",
                          key, msgflg);

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg)) < 0) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        (void)fprintf(stderr, "msgget: msgget succeeded: msqid = %d\n", msqid);


    /*
    * We'll send message type 1
    */

    sbuf.mtype = 1;

    (void)fprintf(stderr, "msgget: msgget succeeded: msqid = %d\n", msqid);

    (void)strcpy(sbuf.mtext, "Hello other process 2.");

    (void)fprintf(stderr, "msgget: msgget succeeded: msqid = %d\n", msqid);

    buf_length = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1;



    /*
    * Send a message.
    */
    if (msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buf_length, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0) {
        printf("%d, %li, %s, %lu\n", msqid, sbuf.mtype, sbuf.mtext, buf_length);
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(1);
    }

    else
        printf("Message: \"%s\" Sent\n", sbuf.mtext);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: the posted code is missing the setting of the `mtype` field in the message to send.

Comment: in general, `lib.h` does not exist (at least on ubuntu linux 14.04) and contributes nothing to the posted code.   Suggest removing the `#include <lib.h>` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't linking with the library that contains the `msgsnd` and `msgget` functions, so your linker step fails.  I'm not familiar with Minix so I'm not sure where the library is stored or what it is called.  Basically, you need to a `-l<msg>` flag to your linking step.  Where `<msg>` is the name of the library that contains the implementation.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to give a little more details of a small example on how this would look like as my experience with C/C++ is very little.

Comment: Caveat: I do not use `clang`.   clang is trouted as being fully compatible with gcc.   In gcc, a `-L<pathToLibraryies>` and a `-l<shortLibName>` parameters are used to locate/select libraries.   The error messages indicate the libraries are not in the standard location.  So you will need to use the `-L` and `-l` parameters to enable the link step to find the libraries needed.